# Trigger occur error in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I created a trigger when the 'MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO' column in the '002' table was updated.
However, when I update, a trigger error occurs.

Update statements

```
UPDATE TB_REN016_002 A
SET A.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO=7003 
WHERE A.CID=11101000001;
```

Trigger statements

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRI_MEAIN_STAT_EVENT
AFTER 
UPDATE OF MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO ON TB_REN016_002
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 7002 THEN 
        IF :OLD.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 7003 OR :OLD.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 7004 THEN
            UPDATE TB_REN016_003 U 
                SET MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 3001
            WHERE U.CID=:NEW.CID 
                AND U.MEAIN_EVENT_CODE_NO=4003;
            UPDATE TB_REN016_006 E 
                SET EVENT_STAT_CODE_NO = 20001
            WHERE U.CID=:NEW.CID 
                AND E.EVENT_CODE_NO=4003
                AND E.OCUR_DTM=(SELECT MAX(E2.OCUR_DTM) FROM TB_REN016_006 E2 WHERE E2.CID=:NEW.CID AND E2.EVENT_CODE_NO=4003);     
        END IF;
    END IF;
    IF :NEW.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 7003 OR NEW.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 7004 THEN
        UPDATE TB_REN016_003 U 
            SET MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 
                (SELECT A.EVENT_GRD_CODE_NO 
                 FROM TB_REN016_039 A 
                 WHERE EVENT_CODE_NO=4003 
                ) 
        WHERE U.CID=:NEW.CID 
        AND U.MEAIN_EVENT_CODE_NO=4003;  

        INSERT 
            INTO TB_REN016_006 
         ( 
         MEAIN_EVENT_SERI_NO, 
         CID, 
         OCUR_DTM, 
         EVENT_CODE_NO, 
         EVENT_GRD_CODE_NO, 
         EVENT_CTNT, 
         EVENT_FIGR, 
         EVENT_STAT_CODE_NO, 
         EVENT_TRME_STAT_CODE_NO, 
         EVENT_OCUR_CUS 
     ) 
     VALUES 
     ( 
         MEAIN_EVENT_SEQ.nextval, 
         :NEW.CID, 
         SYSDATE,  
         4003, 
         (SELECT A.EVENT_GRD_CODE_NO FROM TB_REN016_039 A WHERE EVENT_CODE_NO=4003 ), 
         (SELECT A.EVENT_OCUR_CUS_EXPL FROM TB_REN016_039 A WHERE EVENT_CODE_NO=4003), 
         -1, 
         20002,  
         21001,  
         (SELECT A.EVENT_DSPO_MTHD_EXPL FROM TB_REN016_039 A WHERE EVENT_CODE_NO=4003 )  
     );

)
    END IF;
END;
/
```

When the column 'MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO' is changed to 7002, update the tables 'TB_REN016_003' and 'TB_REN016_006'. If the column '700_' changes to 7003 or 7004, update the table 'TB_REN016_003' and insert the table 'TB_REN016_006'.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @KaushikNayak **ORA-04098: trigger 'SWMS.TRI_MEAIN_STAT_EVENT' is invalid and failed re-validation**

Comment: That means it was either not  compiled correctly or some dependencies got changed . Try to compile the trigger again and post the errors.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Thank you. error : **PLS-00201 : identifer 'NEW.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO' must be declared**. It seems that there is an error when referencing the changed column.

Comment: In this statement 


`IF :NEW.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 7003 OR NEW.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO = 7004 THEN` 

colon is missing.  It should be `:NEW.MEAIN_STAT_CODE_NO`

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! I solved it thanks to you.